# Error in inline edit code

Tags: jquery

I have a div html containing another nested div

```
<div class="draggable">
   <div class="edit_text">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Now i have a code where i am trying to edit the text of `edit_text` div

Here's my code

```
 if (key == 'edit') {
    alert('hii');
    //$(this).find('.edit_text').remove();
    var content = $(this).find('.edit_text').text();

    var width = $(this).width() - 1;
    var height = $(this).height() - 4;

    var $editbox = $("<input type='text'" +
        "style='width:" + width + ";" +
        "height:" + height + ";" +
        "border:none" +
        "' value='" + content + "' />");


    $(this).find('.edit_text').empty();
    $(this).find('.edit_text').prepend($editbox);
    $editbox.focus();
    $editbox.select();


    $($editbox).bind("blur",

    function () {
        $(this).find('.edit_text').html($($editbox).val());
        alert($($editbox).val());
        $($editbox).remove()
    });
}
```

issue is in this section

```
$(this).find('.edit_text').html($($editbox).val());
alert($($editbox).val());  
$($editbox).remove()
```

when i am clicking outside the div, the alert is displaying the `$editbox.val()`

but once the editbox is removed, the html of the innder div i.e. the `edit_text` is missing somewhat

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $editbox is inside the .edit_text div. Your line of code:

```
$(this).find('.edit_text').html($($editbox).val());
```

is trying to look downwards in the DOM; in fact, you need to look up:

```
$(this).closest('.edit_text').html($($editbox).val());
```

That should also take care of removing the $editbox, so you can probably remove this line:

```
$($editbox).remove()
```